# Does ECC RAM with a Coffee Lake CPU need specific motherboard support?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ecc

I'm preparing to build a new computer, and I'd like to use ECC RAM if possible.  In the past, that required a motherboard with ECC support, but these days it's unclear whether that's still true.

The Wikipedia page "[List of Intel Chipsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets)" has a column for Parity/ECC support in all the tables up to a certain point.  But the section "[5/6/7/8/9 Series Chipsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#5/6/7/8/9_Series_chipsets)" explains that newer chipsets don't have a memory controller because it's part of the processor instead, and the tables from that point onward don't mention ECC at all.  Furthermore, Intel's ARK specifications page for modern chipsets, such as the [H370](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/133284/intel-h370-chipset.html), don't mention ECC, while the ARK pages for CPUs, like the [i3-9100](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134870/intel-core-i3-9100-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html), have a line for "ECC Memory Supported", yes or no.

This leads me to believe that ECC support for modern Intel CPUs does not depend on the motherboard: as long as you have a CPU whose memory controller supports ECC (such as the i3-9100), and a motherboard whose chipset is compatible with the CPU (such as an H370 to go with the 9th-gen i3), ECC RAM should work.

But the [specifications page for the Gigabyte H370M DS3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/H370M-DS3H-rev-10/sp#sp), an H370-based motherboard, says "Support for ECC Un-buffered DIMM 1Rx8/2Rx8 memory modules (operate in non-ECC mode)".  The "operate in non-ECC mode" is what concerns me; that defeats the purpose of buying ECC RAM in the first place.

Will ECC really not work on this board?  If so, what is it about the motherboard that prevents it from working if the RAM and the CPU's memory controller both support it?  Is there a good way to find boards which *do* support ECC with 9th-generation Intel CPUs?  ECC doesn't seem to be available as a filter criterion on shopping sites.

Comment: The motherboard will must support ECC.  The specifications of the board in question seem clear, the board will accept ECC memory modules, but they will not perform error correction.  If you want ECC support go with the Xeon platform, I have yet to find a single Xeon motherboard, that does not support ECC memory.

Comment: But the i3-9100 link in your post contains a note that explicitly says you must have chipset support for ECC, thus mainboard support: ECC Memory Supported indicates processor support for Error-Correcting Code memory. ECC memory is a type of system memory that can detect and correct common kinds of internal data corruption. Note that ECC memory support requires both processor and chipset support.

Answer (score 1):

ECC DIMMs actually are 72-bits wide and have 9 memory chips where non-ECC DIMMs have 8 memory chips and 64 bit datapath. The extra 8 bits hold the ECC code. So, the motherboard must route 72 DQ bits to the DRAM DIMM sockets, and if it doesn't, you can use ECC DIMMs but they will not work for ECC.

Answer (score 1):

I like Dave's answer regarding ECC wiring but would like to add a little: Not only do those extra ECC wires etc. need to be routed, but support for ECC memory has to be implemented in the BIOS's memory init code.

During boot one of the crucial steps is to get RAM working (a very complex procedure) and this is done by the BIOS. Usually the motherboard manufacturer will use code or precompiled binaries given to them by AMD or Intel when making it. For AMD this is AGESA and for Intel this is the FSP (Firmware Support Package). The Coreboot project has lots of info on them. This code starts up a lot of functionality for Intel/AMD systems but the version used to make a particular BIOS may or may not support ECC, or other features (or other processors).

If it doesn't support ECC, it may flatly refuse to get the memory working at all, or it may do the job incorrectly and fail. Either way, the system won't boot. If by some miracle it configures things in a way that does boot, then ECC won't be available.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: only [Intel C240 series chipsets](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/138121/intel-c240-series-chipsets.html) (C242 and C246) supports EUDIMM RAM.

Long story:

I bought Kingston Server Premier 4x EUDIMM KSM29ED8/16HD for my workstation with Ryzen CPU and ASUS motherboard. My previous RAM was Crucial 2x EUDIMM CT16G4WFD8266 and it works perfect. But Kingston Server Premier is defective: it has a temperature instability at 50 degrees Celsius.

After reaching 50 degrees one of Kingston RAM sticks starts droping many ECC *correctable* errors with [syndroms in tight range](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/edac/amd64_edac.c#L3015-L3021). It is a sign that one of memory chips is not stable at 50 degrees. Unfortunately only local Kingston engineer from Taiwan with special equipment can answer what chip at the stick is defective and replace it.

I asked local European Kingston warranty service to make a check of my RAM. They made a test using Coffee Lake CPU i3 8100 and desktop motherboard with result "we have received no ECC errors". I was completely pissed off, because EUDIMM RAM is working in non-ECC mode on any Intel desktop motherboard and ECC error may not appear. Consumer rights protection government service approved my complaint: only Intel C240 series chipsets support EUDIMM in ECC mode for Coffee Lake CPU, Kingston warranty service tried to fool me.

I wanted to start a lawsuit and return back Kingston Server Premier RAM. But  local warranty service said that Kingston warranty service has no required equipment and licensed expert for making a forensic examination anyway. After that I received a call from my local shop and received new good memory sticks. Now shop will try to fight with Kingston warranty service and return back defective sticks to Taiwan.

PS **don't ever buy Kingston Server Premier RAM**, it may have temperature instabilty, Kingston is not making temperature tests and it has low quality warranty service.